# shift and delete keys are working separately just fine, but not when pressed together

Tags: windows-8

I am currently using windows 8.
Shift and delete keys are working separately just fine, but when shift + delete is pressed, nothing happens in any application. Neither is it deleting stuff nor is it working with the browsers. Please help!

Comment: there is a  possibility that yet another key that is neither shift nor delete is stuck. Depending on where you were using the del and shift-del (exploring files working with text) it could be something like a ctrl or alt key? At any rate either a utility program that shows  what key is pressed, or manually testing each key may reveal something?

Answer (score 0):

I would guess this is a hardware limitation. Most keyboards only support a few keypresses at the same time. You can test this by typing "the quick fox jumps over the lazy dog" while holding down *both* shift keys all the way through the sentence.

Try using another keyboard, or maybe even the other shift key.